# browser not showing closing tags from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a page that has a simple table that gets HTML from an ajax call.  Sometimes I want the HTML in the ajax response to close a div and td tag and start another column in the table.  However, the browser is just not registering those closing tags.  I display the ajax response in the console, and they are there.  I assume this is a fact of life with ajax, but it really seems like it should work.  Why doesn't this work and is there a way to make it work?

```
<html>
<script>
function ajaxRequest() {
  try {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  } catch(e1) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    } catch(e2) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      } catch(e3) {
        request = false
      }
    }
  }

  return request
}

function callAjax(module, tag) {
  page = module + ".php"
  request = new ajaxRequest()
  request.open("GET", page, true)
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText != null) {
          console.log("callAjax retrieved:\n" + this.responseText)
          document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = this.responseText
        } else alert("Ajax Error: No data received")
      } else alert("Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
    }
  }

  request.send()
}
</script>

<body onload='javascript: callAjax("returnXYZ", "main")'>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td><div id='main'></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and returnXYZ.php just has...

```
<?php echo "\nLMNOP</div></td><td>XYZ"; ?>
```

Comment: Watch out for implied globals and semi-colon insertion.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using `innerHTML` rather than creating new DOM nodes.

Comment: Exactly as @blurd said. You're trying to put all that html **inside** your `div`. You need to insert `\nLMNOP` into the `div`, then insert the new `td` into the `tr` separately.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  It sounds like I'd have to have the javascript create the new node(s) since that 'main' structure is built before the ajax call.  That doesn't really fit into my existing architecture, so I think I'll have the php figure it out and return all the html as needed.  But I still think it's really weird that the browser just decides to ignore and not even display these closing tags.